# C# application tool to execute sql script and update the sql table

Tags: c#, .net

I have an requirement to automate the update query to run using C# for 4 data base.

And Between the data base we need to have 45 seconds delay to execute below script.

```
Declare @i INT= 1;

While (@i <= 20000)
    Begin

        Begin transaction a1

        Update [DATABSE].[DBO].[TABLE] 
           Set FIELD1 = 0, FIELD2= '', FIELD3='XXXXXX' 
           Where FIELD1!= 0 and FIELD3= 'XXXXXX' and FIELD2!= ''
                And DATEDIFF(second, DATE_WRITTEN + ' ' + replace(TIME_WRITTEN, '.', ':'), GETDATE()) >= 60        
        Commit transaction a1
```

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, but what exactly is your issue ?

Comment: How are you calling this exactly? Anyways put this `WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:45'` before the transaction.

Comment: On another note you may timeout by the time this done as well.

Comment: are you requesting people to solve your requirement ?

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to document yourself on [ADO.NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/) to communicate with the sql server DBS.

Then for timing the script executions you either need to use a [Stopwatch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch?view=netcore-3.1)
OR
configure it as a [Windows Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/windows-services/walkthrough-creating-a-windows-service-application-in-the-component-designer) which will run every 45 seconds.

About the code, I recommend you try yourself. StackOverflow it's not a coding service, you get help on already written code which you should provide. No one will write that for you.